# How do I create non fully connected layers in skflow?

Tags: machine-learning, skflow

I want to create a more complex architecture than requires layers connected in a custom way.Can I achive this in skflow ? And if not which framework is best ?
Thanks

Comment: There is no best. But [keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras) is very very popular and can do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I ll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own custom model function or even build your own estimator. For example, you can find a ResNet example under tensorflow/examples/learn implemented using TF.Learn (originally skflow).